# Как настроить стекирование двух коммутаторов QSW3750

Tags: коммутатор

Пытаюсь разобраться с настройкой стекирования на коммутаторах QTECH QSW-3750 - какие настройки нужно задать на каждом коммутаторе?- Также, как управлять стеком и добавлять/удалять коммутаторы из него без нарушений в сети? Попробовал руководства, но нужна помощь с пониманием.

Буду благодарен за советы, возможно, даже примеры конфигураций, чтобы успешно настроить стекирование.

Answer (score 1):

Настройки коммутаторов серии QSW-3300/3310/3750(TX/F)/8200(RQ) - одинаковые.

При помощи стекирования можно объединить до восьми штук в единое логическое устройство с общим айпишником. Особенностью данной серии является возможность сборки в стек коммутаторов с различной аппаратной реализацией.

Процесс настройки логического стека.

В стек собираются коммутаторы с одинаковой версией ПО. Но если версии ПО отличаются, то можно синхронизировать прошивки внутри стека. Подробности Вы можете узнать, открыв мануал по настройке стекирования коммутаторов QSW-3300 на нашем FTP сервере. Также информацию по синхронизации можно найти в нашей статье «Обновление стека коммутаторов».

```
(QSW-3750) #configure 

(QSW-3750) (Config)#stack 

(QSW-3750) (Config-stack)#stack-port 1/0/25 stack
```

Master определяется произвольно. Это будет устройство, которое загрузилось в первую очередь. Далее все объединяемые коммутаторы присваивают себе идентификатор – "Unit". Значение идентификатора уникально и выбирается из диапазона от 1 до 8.

После ввода команд необходимо сохранить конфигурацию командой #write и перезагрузить оборудование для применения выполненных настроек (#reload).

Один из коммутаторов становится Master, остальные назначаются устройствами Backup или остаются в статусе Slave. Мастер осуществляет управление логическим стеком, в частности, протоколами STP, ARP, LACP и всеми остальными функциями.

На следующем этапе нужно ввести команду switch priority, применяемую для назначения роли Backup определенным устройствам. При настройке задаются параметры:

Unit – идентификатор коммутатора;

Value – указатель приоритета (последовательности) назначения коммутаторов Мастером при недоступности свитча, назначенного по умолчанию. Диапазон значений – 1-15. Устройство, имеющее более высокий приоритет будет выбрано на роль Master, если активный главный сетевой коммутатор выйдет из строя. По умолчанию значение равно 1. При равенстве приоритетов выбирается коммутатор с наименьшим MAC адресом.

Если же одинаков и MAC адрес, то выбор  осуществляется по параметру Running Time – «кто дольше находится в сети тот и Master». Из примера, приведенного ниже, видно, что 1 свитч является Мастером. В случае его отказа роль Мастера будет выполнять 2 свитч (со статусом Oper Stby).

```
#show switch

     Management   Standby Preconfig Plugged-in Switch    Code

SW    Switch         Status Model ID   Model ID  Status    Version
```

---

```
1   Mgmt Sw           BCM-56151    BCM-56151    OK     8.1.1.318

2   Stack Mbr   Oper Stby     BCM-56151    BCM-56151    OK     8.1.1.318

3   Stack Mbr                   BCM-56151    BCM-56151    OK     8.1.1.318

4   Stack Mbr                   BCM-56151            BCM-56151    OK     8.1.1.318
```

Приоритет 0 означает, что данное устройство никогда не станет Master и всегда будет Slave. Если перед аннулированием стека не убран нулевой приоритет, то коммутатор не выйдет из режима стекирования и зависнет в этом состоянии.

Можно принудительно выбрать Backup, перейдя из режима конфигурации в режим Stack и введя команду: #standby unit number.

Если нужно что-то дополнить смотри мануалку по [настройке стекирования коммутаторов](https://www.qtech.ru/education/articles/kak-nastroit-stekirovanie-na-kommutatorakh-qsw-3300-3310-3750-tx-f-8200-rq/) на официальном сайте - ftp://ftp.qtech.ru/Switch/Aggregation/QSW-3300%20%5BEOL%5D/Manual/.